# ionic 3 get text from ion-textarea after clicking a button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, textarea, ionic3

I have an `ion-textarea`in which user can write some content, and I would like to get this text after a button is clicked.
This is the html:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="myInput" (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="New Info"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

```
<button ion-button class="card-button" color="secondary" 
 (click)="addInfo()"> <ion-icon name="add-circle" class="icona-bottone"></ion-
 icon>Add Info</button>
```

I've tried doing this in my .ts file:

```
getItems(textarea) {
    // set q to the value of the textarea
    var q = textarea.srcElement.value;
    this.textSearch = q;
}
addInfo(){
    console.log("You wrote " + this.textSearch)
}
```

but it prints "You wrote `undefined` ". What is the correct way to get the text as a string and use it?

Comment: try to console.log(textarea) in your getItems() method and take a look at the value

Comment: it doesn't print anything

Comment: then your getItems() method is not even called. try to use the ngModel "myInput" instead of this.textSearch in your addInfo()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have used 2-way data bind you can do as shown below.

*.html*

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="myInput" placeholder="New Info"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

*.ts*

```
console.log(this.myInput);//this is your textarea value
```